# Sorting Database Query by GPS Location

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gps, coordinates, geocoding

I am writing a website on Google App Engine in Python and I have a Location datastore entity that has a string property containing GPS coordinates.  I want to let the user search by GPS coordinates and I want to return all locations that at within +/- 10 points of Latitude or Longitude.  Basically what I wanted to do is in the following code but I cannot sort the GPS that way, one because it is a string and two because it is the same property.

```
  inputlocation = self.request.get("userlocation")

        g = geocoders.Google()
        try:
            place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(inputlocation)
        except ValueError:
            geocodespot = g.geocode(inputlocation, exactly_one=False)
            place, (lat, lng) = geocodespot[0]
         GPSlocation = "("+str(lat)+", "+str(lng)+")"
         GPSlocation = float(GPSlocation)

         bound = 10
         upper = GPSlocation + bound
         lower = GPSlocation - bound
         left = GPSlocation + bound
         right = GPSlocation - bound

        if GPSlocation:
            locations = db.GqlQuery("select * from Location where GPSlocation>:1 and where GPSlocation>:2 and where GPSlocation <:3 and where GPSlocation <:4 order by created desc limit 20", upper, lower, left, right)
#example GPSlocation in the datastore = "(37.7699298, -93.4469157)"
```

Can you think of any way to do basically this without having to change the way my datastore is set up?  Is there any way to get that information without just making two properties one for Latitude and one for Longitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Google GAE has a few tools for doing what you want to do:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial
- http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/

the proximity_fetch looks like what you need

```
def proximity_fetch(query, center, max_results=10, max_distance=0):
```

Comment: well the only problem with that is that I cannot compare the lat and long (which are floats) to the GPSlocation in the database entity (because it is a string) and that is what I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to add a Computed Property:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

> Computed properties (ComputedProperty) are read-only properties whose
>   value is computed from other property values by an
>   application-supplied function. The computed value is written to the
>   Datastore so that it can be queried and displayed in the Datastore
>   viewer, but the stored value is ignored when the entity is read back
>   from the Datastore; rather, the value is recomputed by calling the
>   function whenever the value is requested.

```
class SomeEntity(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  name_lower = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.name.lower())

x = SomeEntity(name='Nick')
```

So you'd want some sort of function instead of the lower() above, that computes then updates a new LatFloat, LongFloat in your model. So you get to save your data as two floats as well as a single string. I believe you can just add this and your existing data won't be affected, rather when you try to read or search against that data it'll be computed and returned.

Comment: hmm this looks like just what I need but I guess you can't use it for the regular db class?

Comment: is there any way to convert from db to ndb? or is there even any advantage to using db?

Comment: Ah, you can probably do it somehow with some of the more advanced python magic. Ndb seems to offer many advantages IMHO, including computed properties. Plus caching is automatic. You could write a backend task to copy your data over into ndb models but I don't know of any other conversion methods.

Comment: alright thanks for the help.  It shouldn't be too hard to copy it over I was just looking for a good reason to.  Thanks!